# Differentiate the following expression: $f(x)=2x^2 + 7x - \ln(x^2+1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Differentiate the following expression: $f(x)=2x^2 + 7x - \ln(x^2+1)$

I changed the $\ln(x^2+1)$ to $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$, but I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: What exactly are you having trouble with here ?

Comment: Do you know how to differentiate the other two terms? And are you familiar with the chain rule?

Comment: just use sum and difference rule. We know $\frac{d}{dx}2x^2 = 4x$ and $\frac{d}{dx}7x = 7$

Comment: Be careful about changing the $\ln(x^2+1)$ to $1/(x^2+1)$. You have to use chain rule...

Comment: I know how to use the chain rule but I don't know where to start at this point. My teacher did not really give me a good example on how to solve this type.

Comment: If you have $\ln(x^2+1)$, you see that's a composite function, don't you?

Comment: Do you want to find this using limits or directly?

Comment: $h(x)=f(g(x))=\ln(x^2+1)$ is a composition of functions, where $f(x)=\ln (x)$ and $g(x)=x^2+1$. The derivative of $h(x)$ is given by the Chain Rule: $(f(g(x)))'=f'(g(x))g'(x).$

Answer (score 1):

$4x+7-\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$ by Chain Rule.

Comment: If that's all I had to do was find the derivative of each term, then I understand. I just get confused on what exactly I'm needing to do.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{df}{dx} = 4x + 7 - \frac{d}{d(x^2+1)}\ln(x^2+1)\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+1)$$
$$=4x + 7 - \frac{2x}{(x^2+1)}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$$

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to bring the negative sign into the $ln$ term. Just use the chain rule. 
$$ -\frac{d}{dx}ln(x^2+1)= -\frac{1}{x^2+1}\frac{d}{dx}(x^2+1)= -\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$$

You can technically bring the negative into the expression and get the same answer, but the math gets a bit more laborious.
$$ \frac{d}{dx}ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2+1}\right)= \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x^2+1}}* -\frac{2x}{(x^2+1)^2}= -\frac{2x}{x^2+1} $$

Comment: I don't think he brought the negative into the $\ln$. He said he changed $\ln(x^2+1)$ to $1/(x^2+1)$. If he had changed $(x^2+1)$ to $1/(x^2+1)$ it'd be clear he did that. But like this, it seems more like a failed attempt to derivate that.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, remember that the differential operator is *linear*.  I.e., $\frac{d}{dx}[\alpha f(x) + \beta g(x)] = \alpha \frac{d}{dx}[f(x)] + \beta \frac{d}{dx}[g(x)]$

So, $\frac{d}{dx}[2x^2+7x−\ln(x^2+1)]=2\frac{d}{dx}[x^2] + 7\frac{d}{dx}[x]+\frac{d}{dx}[\ln(x^2+1)]$

> Power rule:
>   $$\frac{d}{dx}[x^k]=kx^{k-1}$$

The second piece of information you need to continue is:

> Chain rule:
>   $$\frac{d}{dx}[(f\circ g)(x)] = (\frac{d}{dx}[f])(g(x))\cdot \frac{d}{dx}[g(x)]$$
>   In alternative notation this is $[f(g(x))]'=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$

So, $\frac{d}{dx}[2x^2+7x−\ln(x^2+1)]=2\frac{d}{dx}[x^2] + 7\frac{d}{dx}[x]+\frac{d}{dx}[\ln(x^2+1)] = 2\cdot(2x) + 7\cdot (1) + \frac{1}{x^2+1}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}[x^2+1]$

$=4x+7+\frac{2x}{x^2+1}$